# How to access Facebook profile of user account

Tags: facebook

Facebook, with its enormous dataset and social connection information, is known to have the ability to profile users. For example, they are often cited as being able to easily predict your voting preference. Is there a way to access the company profile of a user account?

Answer (score 1):

You can use graphsearch to access company profile of user accounts if only they are set to "public".
Facebook also use private data but only for statistic, research and advertisement.